# In a general push-pull DC-DC converter topology, why isn't the magnetizing inductance of the core a design parameter?

Tags: transformer, dc-dc-converter

I'm going through the book *Power Electronics* by Daniel W. Hart, and it mentions in the push-pull converter section that the magnetizing inductance is not a design parameter for the push-pull topology.

Why is that so?

Is it simply because we design the core with high permeability materials, or is there a different reason? I understand why that is the case on the forward converter but have a hard time understanding it in this case. An explanation would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I get the feeling that the next sentence may have the reason. (ideal transformers have infinite  magnetising inductance)

Comment: Because the topology is a transformer, the primary inductance is not part of the basic circuit, only a loss mechanism, unlike a boost or flyback where energy is stored in the inductance. So "assume it is large" and do the basic design, then justify that assumption and factor in the magnetising loss at the detail design stage.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. It felt out of place since the book seemed to take the magnetizing inductance into account for all the previous topologies(forward, flyback).  Thanks.

Comment: @Narutorunner11 are we done with this question you raised yesterday? Do you have any residual concerns about any answer? Do you know how to terminate the Q and A session if you are fully satisfied with answer(s)? If you have comments to make about answers in order to get clarity, leave them under the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I got it cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *the magnetizing inductance is not a design parameter for the push-pull
> topology. Why is that so? An explanation would be appreciated.*

Strictly speaking **it is** something you **should** take into account on a practical design. This is because of leakage inductance i.e. coupling between primary windings isn't 100%. Therefore, when one of the push-pull transistors deactivates, there will be an extra back-emf (above the natural back-emf of \$2\times V_s\$) that isn't quenched by the other primary winding and its transistor.

You might therefore design snubber circuits on each primary half that ensured the peak back-emf voltage produced does not exceed the rating of the push-pull switching transistors.

Also, you should include the extra current due to magnetization in rating the transistors. However, if you have a high magnetization inductance, this may be a small percentage of the full load current seen by the primary and so, it might be neglected in some cases.

> *Is it simply because we design the core with high permeability
> materials, or is there a different reason?*

Well, we do try and do this but it isn't a black or white situation and, in many cases, we do need to *consider* the magnetization current.